# Image scroll fadeIn, go to next section when done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

**Things I'm trying to accomplish:**

1. Images go to the next one based on scroll.
2. The images will cycle through, and when they are all done the view will proceed to the bottom section. A problem with what I have right now is that, when I scroll, the view doesn't stay on the image, but moves on to the rest of the page--so even if the image changes, the image is no longer in the viewport.
3. `fadeIn` when it goes to the next image (or use another animation).
4. When scrolling up, it goes back up the image sequence.

If there is a jQuery plugin that does this, please feel free to refer.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/gcSe8/145/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".img-container > img").fadeIn("slow").attr('src',' http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/13/007Squirtle_Pokemon_Mystery_Dungeon_Explorers_of_Sky.png/revision/latest?cb=20150105230449');
        } else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 110) {
   $(".img-container > img").fadeIn("slow").attr('src','http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/5/52/417Pachirisu_Pokemon_Ranger_Shadows_of_Almia.png/revision/latest?cb=20141021151508');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.left{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
body,html{
margin:0px;
}
.bottom{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  background:gray;
 
}
.bottom p{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:40px;
}
.img-container{
  height:700px;
  width:100%;
}
.img-container img{
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
.img-container p{
  position:absolute;
text-align:center;
color:#00FFF5;
font-size:30px;
margin:300px;
background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">

  <p>
  This is fixed!
  </p>

</div>
<div class="img-container">
<p>
This section should stay focused on image until all images have been scrolled through and then it can go to the bottom.
</p>
  <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/unnbgkdbmsszmazgxkmr.jpg">
  
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <p>
  Please don't cover me
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Check http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#helprate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var images_index = 0;
  var act_cycle = 0;
  var n_cycles = 5;
  var images = ["https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/unnbgkdbmsszmazgxkmr.jpg","http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/13/007Squirtle_Pokemon_Mystery_Dungeon_Explorers_of_Sky.png/revision/latest?cb=20150105230449","http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/5/52/417Pachirisu_Pokemon_Ranger_Shadows_of_Almia.png/revision/latest?cb=20141021151508",]
  $(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
    if ($(".img-container").is(':hover')){   
      if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
       if(images_index < images.length-1){
          $(document).scrollTop(".img-container");
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          if(++act_cycle % n_cycles == 0){
            act_cycle = 0;
            $(".img-container > img").hide().attr('src',images[++images_index]).fadeIn("slow");
          } 
        }
      } 
      else {
        if(images_index > 0){
          $(document).scrollTop(".img-container");
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          if (--act_cycle == -n_cycles){
            act_cycle = 0;
            $(".img-container > img").hide().attr('src',images[--images_index]).fadeIn("slow");
          }
        }
      }
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.left{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 2;
}
body,html{
margin:0px;
}
.bottom{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  background:gray;
 
}
.bottom p{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:40px;
}
.img-container{
  height:700px;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.img-container img{
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.img-container p{
  position:absolute;
text-align:center;
color:#00FFF5;
font-size:30px;
margin:300px;
background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <p>
  This is fixed!
  </p>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <p>
    This section should stay focused on image until all images have been scrolled through and then it can go to the bottom.
  </p>
  <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/unnbgkdbmsszmazgxkmr.jpg">
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <p>
    Please don't cover me
  </p>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

> Images go to the next one based on scroll.

To solve this I just put in an array all the images, changing the src depending on the index of the array that I'm updating depending on the scroll direction (see [wheelDelta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel#wheelDelta_wheelDeltaX_and_wheelDeltaY_value))

> The images will cycle through, and when they are all done the view
>   will proceed to the bottom section. A problem with what I have right
>   now is that, when I scroll, the view doesn't stay on the image, but
>   moves on to the rest of the page--so even if the image changes, the
>   image is no longer in the viewport.

To prevent the normal scroll I used the DOMMouseScroll and mousewheel events, then [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) and I only fire this logic if the `img-container` is hover.

> fadeIn when it goes to the next image (or use another animation).

I just first `fadeOut`, the change src and finally `fadeIn`

> When scrolling up, it goes back up the image sequence.

Solved with the array of images.

In adition, I add some z-index, because of the behavior of the jQuerys fadeIn/Out and a `scrollTop` to fix the view on the image when is changing

**UPDATE:** If you want to change the image in a certain numbers of 'cycles' you can add a var to control it (here is `n_cycles`, change his value to change the number of cycles you want wait until image changes, I set it to 5 as you say in comments).

Comment: Thanks, I have a followup question, what if I wanted the images to change on, let's say 5 mouse wheel cycles, right now it looks like it does it in one cycle which seems a little short.

Comment: You can add a counter and update his value on every mousewhell. Check the update.